# How to select oldest value in a tuple

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using sqlplus in Oracle and my question is:

- Find the bookID, title, author, and publish year of the book that has the oldest publish-year.
- Then Find the name of the author(s) that has the largest number of different books owned by the
  library (multiple copies of the same book only count as one book).

Here is my database:

```
 drop table history;
 drop table currentloan;
 drop table member;
 drop table book;

 /*
    creates table with 6 variables
    assigns one primary key
    uses different data types for different cases
 */  

create table Book
(bookID             number(12) Primary Key,
 ISBN               number(13),
 title              varchar(50),
 author             varchar(20),
 publish_year       number(4),
 category           char(11));

 /*
    Inserts tuples with matching variables 
    uses different book categories for testing purposes  
 */ 

insert into Book values('7839494', '9780143122784', 'Guitar Zero', 'Gary Marcus', '2012', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('7839495', '9780143122784', 'Guitar Zero', 'Gary Marcus', '2012', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('7839496', '9780143122784', 'Guitar Zero', 'Gary Marcus', '2012', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('1405904', '9780071812436', 'Oracle Database 12c PL/SQL Programming', 'Michael McLaughlin', '2014', 'reference');
insert into Book values('9890304', '9781449343033', 'Oracle Essentials: Oracle Database 12c', 'Rick Greenwald', '2013', 'reference');
insert into Book values('1893409', '9781598635034', 'Music Theory for Computer Musicians', 'Michael Hewitt', '2008', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('3848598', '9781119247791', 'Java All-in-One For Dummies', 'Doug Lowe', '2017', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('3848599', '9781119247791', 'Java All-in-One For Dummies', 'Doug Lowe', '2017', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('3049891', '9780679805274', 'Oh, the Places Youll Go', 'Dr. Seuss', '1990', 'Childrens');
insert into Book values('3049892', '9780679805274', 'Oh, the Places Youll Go', 'Dr. Seuss', '1990', 'Childrens');
insert into Book values('3049893', '9780679805274', 'Oh, the Places Youll Go', 'Dr. Seuss', '1990', 'Childrens');
insert into Book values('9839209', '9780072465631', 'Database Management Systems', 'Raghu Ramakrishnan', '2008', 'reference');
insert into Book values('3234567', '9780316605106', 'Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare', 'Darren Shan', '2002', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('3234568', '9780316605106', 'Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare', 'Darren Shan', '2002', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('3234569', '9780316605106', 'Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare', 'Darren Shan', '2002', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('3234570', '9780316605106', 'Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare', 'Darren Shan', '2002', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('1239480', '9781421539645', 'DeathNote Black Edition Vol. 1', 'Tsugumi Ohba', '2010', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('5467878', '9780877798095', 'Merriam_Websters Collegiate Dictionary', 'Merriam_Webster', '2003', 'reference');
insert into Book values('5467879', '9780877798095', 'Merriam_Websters Collegiate Dictionary', 'Merriam_Webster', '2003', 'reference');
commit;

 /*
    Creates member table with 6 variables 
    assigns one primary key 
    uses not null to ensure efficiency
  */ 
create table Member
(memberID            number(15) Primary Key,
 lastname            char(15),
 firstname           char(15) not null,
 address             varchar(30),
 phone_number        number(10),
 limit               number(3));


 /*
    Uses insert to fill member table with values 
    ensures values differ for testing  
*/

insert into Member values ('00986845', 'Guevara', 'Merlyn', '9705 hardwood ln', '9806369324', '5');
insert into Member values ('00425663', 'Courtney', 'Kacey', '1520 glengarry dr', '9848339522', '5');
insert into Member values ('00327889',  'Wells', 'Trey', '650 zack rd', '9802428333', '5');
insert into Member values ('00546283', 'Lopez', 'Manny', '123 Road st', '7046368300', '10');
insert into Member values ('00728432', 'Mondragon', 'Alpha', '6100 Raven peak dr', '7043028422', '5'); 
insert into Member values ('00345674', 'Jones', 'David', '4321 Rowan Way', '9803334564', '7');
insert into Member values ('00456742', 'Smith', 'John', '3456 Circle Pl', '7043239098', '8');
commit;


  /*    Generates table to track books checked out 
        Initializes 4 different variables
 */
create table CurrentLoan
( memberID           number(15),
  bookID             number(12),
  loan_date          varchar(10),
  due_date           varchar(10),
  FOREIGN KEY(bookID) REFERENCES book(bookID),
  Foreign key(memberID) REFERENCES member(memberID));


 /*
    uses insert to add currently checked out books  
*/

insert into Currentloan values('00986845', '7839494', '09/28/2018', '12/28/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00546283', '1405904', '08/12/2018', '11/12/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00327889', '9839209', '09/05/2018', '12/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00345674', '1239480', '08/04/2018', '10/12/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '1893409', '07/04/2018', '10/04/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '5467878', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '7839496', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '3848599', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '3049892', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '3234569', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '3234568', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '3049891', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '3848598', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '5467879', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '3234570', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
commit;


 /*     Generates table of books checked out in the past
     Initializes 4 variables 
    deterines primary and foreign keys
 */
create table History
(memberID            number(15),
 bookID              number(12),
 loan_date           varchar(10) Primary Key,
 return_date         varchar(10),
 Foreign Key(bookID) References book(bookID),
 Foreign Key(memberID) References member(memberID));
 /*
    uses insert to specify previously checked out books. 
 */
insert into History values ('00728432', '5467878', '02/08/2017', '04/05/2017');
insert into History values ('00986845', '3234567', '09/12/2017', '10/10/2017');
insert into History values ('00728432', '3848598', '07/14/2016', '09/04/2017');
insert into History values ('00986845', '1239480', '11/14/2016', '01/26/2017');
insert into History values ('00456742', '3234569', '07/05/2016', '09/02/2016');
commit;
```

I thought my query was correct but I keep getting the error stating I can't do this operation in the having clause

```
Select bookID, title, author, publish_yea, Min(publish_year)
from Book 
group by bookID
having publish_year = Min(publish_year);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the error message `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` from your query. You are missing 3 column names in the group by clause, it should read like this to avoid that error:

```
Select bookID, title, author, publish_year, Min(publish_year)
from Book 
group by bookID , TITLE, AUTHOR, PUBLISH_YEAR
having publish_year = Min(publish_year);
```

**BUT**, that query will not achieve what you are seeking. You are grouping by a unique value (the primary key), so you get every row of the table returned by that query.

> ```
> Select bookID, title, author, publish_year, Min(publish_year)
> from Book 
> group by bookID, title, author, publish_year
> having publish_year = Min(publish_year)
> ```
>
> ```
> BOOKID  | TITLE                                  | AUTHOR             | PUBLISH_YEAR | MIN(PUBLISH_YEAR)
> :------ | :------------------------------------- | :----------------- | :----------- | :----------------
> 1893409 | Music Theory for Computer Musicians    | Michael Hewitt     | 2008         | 2008             
> 3848598 | Java All-in-One For Dummies            | Doug Lowe          | 2017         | 2017             
> 3234567 | Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare    | Darren Shan        | 2002         | 2002             
> 7839495 | Guitar Zero                            | Gary Marcus        | 2012         | 2012             
> 3049891 | Oh, the Places Youll Go                | Dr. Seuss          | 1990         | 1990             
> 3049893 | Oh, the Places Youll Go                | Dr. Seuss          | 1990         | 1990             
> 7839496 | Guitar Zero                            | Gary Marcus        | 2012         | 2012             
> 3234568 | Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare    | Darren Shan        | 2002         | 2002             
> 5467878 | Merriam_Websters Collegiate Dictionary | Merriam_Webster    | 2003         | 2003             
> 3049892 | Oh, the Places Youll Go                | Dr. Seuss          | 1990         | 1990             
> 1239480 | DeathNote Black Edition Vol. 1         | Tsugumi Ohba       | 2010         | 2010             
> 9890304 | Oracle Essentials: Oracle Database 12c | Rick Greenwald     | 2013         | 2013             
> 3848599 | Java All-in-One For Dummies            | Doug Lowe          | 2017         | 2017             
> 7839494 | Guitar Zero                            | Gary Marcus        | 2012         | 2012             
> 3234570 | Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare    | Darren Shan        | 2002         | 2002             
> 5467879 | Merriam_Websters Collegiate Dictionary | Merriam_Webster    | 2003         | 2003             
> 1405904 | Oracle Database 12c PL/SQL Programming | Michael McLaughlin | 2014         | 2014             
> 9839209 | Database Management Systems            | Raghu Ramakrishnan | 2008         | 2008             
> 3234569 | Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare    | Darren Shan        | 2002         | 2002
> ```

As given by Turbero, a subquery for the global earliest year will work:

> ```
> select bookID, title, author, publish_year
> from Book
> WHERE publish_year = (SELECT min(publish_year) FROM Book)
> ```
>
> ```
> BOOKID  | TITLE                   | AUTHOR    | PUBLISH_YEAR
> :------ | :---------------------- | :-------- | :-----------
> 3049891 | Oh, the Places Youll Go | Dr. Seuss | 1990        
> 3049892 | Oh, the Places Youll Go | Dr. Seuss | 1990        
> 3049893 | Oh, the Places Youll Go | Dr. Seuss | 1990
> ```

OR, and alternative could be to use a window function `rank()` (or `dense_rank()`)

> ```
> select  bookID, title, author, publish_year
> from (
>       select  bookID, title, author, publish_year
>          , rank() over(order by publish_year) rnk
>       from book
>      ) d
> where rnk = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> BOOKID  | TITLE                   | AUTHOR    | PUBLISH_YEAR
> :------ | :---------------------- | :-------- | :-----------
> 3049891 | Oh, the Places Youll Go | Dr. Seuss | 1990        
> 3049893 | Oh, the Places Youll Go | Dr. Seuss | 1990        
> 3049892 | Oh, the Places Youll Go | Dr. Seuss | 1990
> ```

See all the above queries online here *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5e8b5c027422991b309b224ae1591bb)*

Answer (score 1):

There is a small typo in your select, "publish_yea".

I preloaded your database in https://sqliteonline.com/ and then run your query with the typo fixed:

```
select bookID, title, author, publish_year, Min(publish_year)
from Book 
group by bookID
having publish_year = Min(publish_year);
```

It worked.

But that query gives you the min publish year of each group, not the global min. This query will do it:

```
select bookID, title, author, publish_year
from Book
WHERE publish_year = (SELECT min(publish_year) FROM Book)
```

Comment: Really? it worked when you ran it? that's odd cause if i fix the typo it still gives me this error: having publish_year = Min(publish_year)
       *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Also your second query makes a lot more sense thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12C+, you can use `fetch first`.  Assuming you want only one row:

```
Select bookID, title, author, publish_yea, publish_year
from Book 
order by publish_year desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

In earlier versions, the `rank()` solution provided in another answer is probably the best approach.